# Sending emails from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email

I have trouble with sending mails via PowerShell, all information is being loaded from .txt file. Code looks like this:

```
$path = "C:\tmp\seznam.txt"
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$to = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Get-Content -Path $path -TotalCount 5)[-1]
$from = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Get-Content -Path $path -TotalCount 1)
$attachment = (Get-Content -Path $path -TotalCount 4)[-1]
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to)
$msg.subject = (Get-Content -Path $path -TotalCount 2)[-1]
$msg.body = (Get-Content -Path $path -TotalCount 3)[-1]
$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$smtp.host = "smtprelay.ok.aero"
$SMTP.Port = 25   ###not requried
#$smtp.Send($from,$To,$subject,$body)
$smtp.send($msg)
```

But I´m keep getting same error, which looks like this:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Odeslání e-mailu se nezdařilo."
At C:\Users\salema\Documents\Powershell_project_1\mail.ps1:15 char:1
+ $smtp.send($msg)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

I have no clue, what can cause such an error. Can anyone help explain it please?

Comment: try using the cmdlet `Send-MailMessage` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz When I tryed using send-mailmessage I had to use credentials, which I am trying to avoid, so the scrip can be run by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

try sending the mail without the attachment and simple strings like

```
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$to = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress('my.em@il')
$from = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress('my.em@il')
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to)
$msg.subject = ('mail subject')
$msg.body = ('mail body text')
$smtp.host = "smtprelay.ok.aero"
$SMTP.Port = 25   ###not requried
$smtp.send($msg)
```

if this works try adding the attachment like

```
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($path, 'text/plain')
$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
```

Comment: I tryed exactly as you said, but with same result (even without attachment). Is it possible that some restriction were made by company I work in? Because I´m running out of ideas.

Comment: so maybe you have to authenticate here also. have you tried adding the credentials `$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user , $pass);`?

Comment: also ssl might be required `$smtp.EnableSsl = $true`

Comment: Yes, I did everything you mentioned, but I´m reciving still the same error report.